# Why __RequestVerificationToken in not found in Mono 4.2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, antiforgerytoken

ASP.NET MVC4 application uses cross-site forgery prevention according to MVC4 doc.

In form there is hidden variable

...

and cookie

Browsers posts cookie

__RequestVerificationToken

Post method hander is decorated with

```
[HttpPost,ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

Attributes. https  protocil is ised. It worked earlier. After application was upgraded in submitting form in some cases produces exception

```
    System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException
    The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Error processing request.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryToken fieldToken) <0x4098fc20 + 0x003af> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext) <0x4098e540 + 0x00092> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate () <0x4098e490 + 0x0006f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization (System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext) <0x4098e420 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) <0x41389eb0 + 0x00097> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e (System.AsyncCallback asyncCallback, System.Object asyncState) <0x4138957
```

how to fix this so that Request Verification Token can used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you description, you are telling Action method to check the token but your form is not sending it, hence the missing __RequestVerificationToken

__RequestVerificationToken is generated by calling helper method `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in form

For example:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Account")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}`

for more info, please see:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks

Comment: This is present. This exception occurs only in some broesers. Server is running in Debiand It started to occur after upgrading to Mono 4.2.2. In earlier version of Mono it does not occur.

Comment: `__RequestVerificationToken` cookie present in response. It seems that new Mono does not find it